# How can width and height of <a> is expanded to parent <td>?

Tags: css, html-table, hyperlink

I'm working on React and `<a>` element in `<td>` must be expanded to fit width and height of `<td>`. It means that when I click `<td>` element, hyperlink of `<a>` has to work as expected. How can I achieve this behavior **without `position` property?** I know `position` property can solve this issue, but it could be worse by using this property. Therefore, I wanna solve this without this property.

**HTML**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td1</a></td>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td2</a></td>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td3</a></td>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

td:hover a {
  color: purple;
}
```

**Context**

- I'm using CSS framework and cannot remove `padding` of `td`
- `a` must cover `width` and `height` of `td`

Comment: You can add 'display:block' property to 'a'.

Comment: @NileshChavan But parent element has `padding` so it doesn't work and `height` cannot be solved also.

Comment: you should give padding to 'a' not to 'td' as per CSS box model

Answer (score 0):

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* padding: 16px; //Remove padding and add it to a tag. */ 
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px;
  background: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;

}

td:hover a {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td1</a></td>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td2</a></td>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td3</a></td>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you have to keep the property `padding` in `td` tag,

There is only one option that is `position:absolute`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm using CSS framework so I cannot remove padding of `td`

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margin then inherit the padding:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background:#f2f2f2;
  display:block;
  margin:-16px;
  padding:inherit;
}

td:hover a {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td1</a></td>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td2</a></td>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td3</a></td>
    <td><a href="https://google.com">td4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```